# C++: Trying to create a Run key, All i get is Chinese characters in registry.

Tags: c++, registry

Please save me! I am new to this, trying to figure this out. I would like to have my program add a run key to run itself on startup . Here is "my" code:

```
HKEY hKey = 0;
RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
                0,
                KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
                &hKey );
const unsigned char Path[ MAX_PATH ] = "C:\\test.exe";
RegSetValueEx( hKey, L"Testing", 0, 1, Path, strlen("C:\\test.exe") );
RegCloseKey(hKey);
```

This "works" except they key added reads "㩃瑜獥⹴硥" under data . Took me a while to figure out that the key is going to WoW6432Node too, thought it complied but wasn't working for the first 5 hours, much head to wall action there...

I am sure this has something to do with the way my string is formatted, ANSII vs ASCII vs the other 10 types of strings C++ doesn't seem to be able to convert between... I've tried using (BYTE*)"C:\virus.exe" and anything else i could think of... If i set the length to 1, the first character shows fine. But if its any other length, Chinese starts to show again.

Please help! I am about ready to start choking kittens here!

Comment: You are mixing UTF-16 (`wchar_t`) strings and plain ASCII (`char`) strings.

Comment: You use wide strings everywhere else. Why is `Path` different?

Comment: this was the only way it would compile :( i tried using
    RegSetValueEx( hKey, L"Testing", 0, 1, wstr, strlen("C:\\test.exe") );
but i could not convert this to the type needed by method. Its asking for const BYTE, wasnt able to typecast either. I am so lost :(

Comment: Unrelated issue: the fact that your registry keys end up in WoW6432Node is probably becuase of this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: interesting read. i kinda figured, i felt silly after 5 hours of not checking for this. ive always avoided the registry, one of my last frontiers. I'll try to read up on it later lol. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @Rufflewind `char` does not imply ASCII (which is quite unlikely). `char` is just the code unit size for the character encoding; One or more chars are used to represent a particular character. Windows-1252 is commonly used. It has 251 characters, all encoded in one char each.

Comment: @TomBlodget You're right.  I should've said "ANSI".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
const unsigned char Path[ MAX_PATH ] = "C:\\test.exe";
```

You have defined an ANSI string and then attempted to use the Unicode (UTF-16) version of `RegSetValueEx`:

```
RegSetValueEx( hKey, L"Testing", 0, 1, Path, strlen("C:\\test.exe") );
```

Under the hood, `RegSetValueEx` is a macro that aliases to `RegSetValueExW` because you defined the macro `UNICODE`.

The correct solution is to use a Unicode string literal:

```
const wchar_t Path[] = L"C:\\test.exe";
RegSetValueEx( hKey, L"Testing", 0, 1, (const BYTE *) Path, sizeof(Path) );
```

Here I used `sizeof` because the string is an array of characters whose size is known at compile time.  For dynamic strings, use `(wcslen(Path) + 1) * sizeof(*Path)` instead.

Note: There is no need to specify the length of a constant literal in the declaration because the compiler can automatically deduce that in this specific scenario.  It's also bad idea to duplicate the string literal inside your `strlen`/`wcslen` because if it goes out of sync your code could be broken and trigger undefined behavior.

Comment: I feel we are so close, but i get a compiler error:
IntelliSense: argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const BYTE *"

Comment: Worth noting that it's not ASCII-encoded. ASCII is a 7-bit encoding and this encoding is most likely something like Windows 1252, but can differ.

Comment: @JeniaCraighead, It really should work just `reinterpret_cast`ing it. That's the unfortunate thing about the winapi.

Comment: Never mind, was able to typecast this at least. we have progress, registry now says "C:\te"

Comment: I've edited it.  Because `RegSetValueEx` accepts *arbitrary data*, it accepts an arbitrary binary buffer.  You should change the size of the string to be twice as large (and must also include the null terminator).

Comment: I see! thanks! i tried hardcoding the size to 32 and that worked, but i definitely like your way better!